# Stop JComponent from repainting when state changes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint, jcomponent

I'm sure, this is something like a super stupid standard problem, but I spent hours searching and trying to get this fixed, but it just won't work... I just can't find my mistake here...

I'm trying to build a simple program that prints something on a JComponent. The paintComponent()-Method refers to some variables and I want the JComponent ONLY to repaint, if i say so! But it always repaints whenever i change the variables...

Heres the code of my 2 classes:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimplePaint extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private PaintingCanvas pc;


public SimplePaint() {

    super("SimplePaint");

    this.pc = new PaintingCanvas();
    this.pc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));


    this.add(pc);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimplePaint sp = new SimplePaint();

    sp.pc.setxStart(50);
    sp.pc.setyStart(60);
    sp.pc.setxEnd(140);
    sp.pc.setyEnd(300);

}



}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintingCanvas extends JComponent {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int xStart, yStart;
private int xEnd, yEnd;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.fillRect(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
}

/**
 * @param xStart the xStart to set
 */
public void setxStart(int xStart) {
    this.xStart = xStart;
}

/**
 * @param yStart the yStart to set
 */
public void setyStart(int yStart) {
    this.yStart = yStart;
}


/**
 * @param xEnd the xEnd to set
 */
public void setxEnd(int xEnd) {
    this.xEnd = xEnd;
}

/**
 * @param yEnd the yEnd to set
 */
public void setyEnd(int yEnd) {
    this.yEnd = yEnd;
}

}
```

What it displays: The Canvas with a rectangle (50, 60, 140, 300)...

What is should display: The blank canvas, and if i then put sp.pc.repaint() or something like that in the main method, it should repaint and therefore show the rectangle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make any assumption on when and how many times `paintComponent` will be called. When making the frame visible, it wille be invoked. If you maximize your frame also, etc... There are many situations when `paintComponent` will be invoked.

The solution is pretty easy:

- Add a flag (`boolean drawRectangle = false;`) on your `PaintingCanvas` class
- In `paintComponent` check the value of the flag and draw (or not) the rectangle accordingly
- When you want the rectangle to appear, toggle the value of the flag

Comment: Aaaaah, thanks a lot :) that's even so easy, that i feel ashamed for not getting that idea myself... :O

Comment: But this evokes another question: 

I read some tutorials, including this one http://www.java-forum.org/272862-post7.html (the part below "RICHTIGER ANSATZ"), and now wonder, why i have to call repaint myself, if i'm working with buttons for example...?!

they have variables for color and shape that change when a button is pressed and it does only change, if the actionListener explicitly calls repaint?!

Comment: @user2393914 Calling `repaint` is a way to indicate to the `RepaintManager` that the internal state of your component has changed and that you want it to be repainted. Eventually, your paintComponent method will be invoked and your component will be refreshed. Calling `repaint` is usually necessary for custom components.